# 'PHP' Здравствуйте, я написал код регистрации с сохранением в текстовом файле, помогите сделать авторизацию?

Tags: php, html, php7, php5

Регистрация:

```
<table> 
<form method=post> 
<tr><td>Имя:</td><td><input type=text name=name></td></tr> 
<tr><td>Пароль:</td><td><input type=password name=pass></td></tr> 
<tr><td>Пароль:</td><td><input type=password name=pass_again></td></tr> 
<tr><td>e-mail:</td><td><input type=text name=email></td></tr> 
<tr><td>URL:</td><td><input type=text name=url></td></tr> 
<tr><td></td><td><input type=submit value='Зарегистрировать'></td></tr> 
</form> 
</table> 
<?php 
$file = 'text.txt';
$text = file_get_contents($file);
echo file_get_contents( 'text.txt' );
  // Обработчик HTML-формы 

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////// 
  // 1. Блок проверки правильности данных 
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////// 
  // Удаляем лишние пробелы 
  $_POST['name'] = trim($_POST['name']); 
  $_POST['pass'] = trim($_POST['pass']); 
  $_POST['pass_again'] = trim($_POST['pass_again']); 
  // Проверяем не пустой ли суперглобальный массив $_POST 
  if(empty($_POST['name'])) exit(); 
  // Проверяем правильно ли заполнены обязательные поля 
  if(empty($_POST['name'])) exit('Поле "Имя" не заполнено'); 
  if(empty($_POST['pass'])) exit('Одно из полей "Пароль" не заполнено'); 
  if(empty($_POST['pass_again'])) exit('Одно из полей "Пароль" не заполнено'); 
  if($_POST['pass'] != $_POST['pass_again']) exit('Пароли не совпадают'); 
  // Если введён e-mail проверяем его на соответсвие 
  if(!empty($_POST['email'])) 
  { 
    if(!preg_match("|^[0-9a-z_]+@[0-9a-z_^\.]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$|i", $_POST['email'])) 
    { 
      exit('Поле "E-mail" должно соответствовать формату somebody@somewhere.ru'); 
    } 
  } 

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////// 
  // 2. Блок проверки имени на уникальность 
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////// 
  // Имя файла данных 
  $filename = "text.txt";  
  // Проверяем не было ли переданное имя 
  // зарегистрировано ранее 
  $arr = file($filename); 
  foreach($arr as $line) 
  { 
    // Разбиваем строку по разделителю :: 
    $data = explode("::",$line); 
    // В массив $temp помещаем имена уже зарегистрированных 
    // посетителей 
    $temp[] = $data[0]; 
  } 
  // Проверяем не содержится ли текущее имя 
  // в массиве имён $temp 
  if(in_array($_POST['name'], $temp)) 
  { 
    exit("Данное имя уже зарегистрировано, пожалуйста, выберите другое"); 
  } 

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////// 
  // 3. Блок регистрации пользователя 
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////// 
  // Помещаем данные в текстовый файл 
  $fd = fopen($filename, "a"); 
  if(!$fd) exit("Ошибка при открытии файла данных"); 
  $str = $_POST['name']."::". 
         $_POST['pass']."::". 
         $_POST['email']."::". 
         $_POST['url']."\r\n"; 
  fwrite($fd,$str); 
  fclose($fd); 
  // Осуществляем перезагрузку страницы, 
  // чтобы сбросить POST-данные 
  echo "<HTML><HEAD> 
<META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0; URL=index.html'>
        </HEAD></HTML>"; 
?>
```

Comment: Следующий вопрос будет "Здравствуйте, вы мне написали код авторизации, напишите весь остальной код тоже" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем ты работаешь с текстовыми файлами? Изучай PHP в связке с MySQL, почитай про классы, про ООП. Это куда полезнее, чем тратить время на "мёртвые" задачи.

Для примера, вот метод класса для авторизации:

```
public function Login($t_login, $t_password)
{
    $m = new Modules(); // экземляр другого класса
    $login = $m->SafeInput($t_login);
    $password = $m->SafeInput($t_password);
    $hashedPass = md5($password);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `login` = '{$login}' AND `password` = '{$hashedPass}' LIMIT 1";
    $query = $this->connection->query($sql);

    if($query->num_rows == 1){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['user_id'];
            $_SESSION['login'] = $row['login'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        array_push($this->errors, "Неверный логин или пароль");
    }
}
```

А вот обработка формы авторизации:

```
$user = new User(); // Экземляр класса, с помощью которого ты получишь доступ к методу с авторизацией

    if (isset($_POST['enter'])) {
        $user->Login($_POST['login'], $_POST['password']);
    }
```